# Listar dos Arrays en un mismo ListView

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas, esto va ser algo extenso pero acá va, mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo dos arrays que envío de una Actividad a otra vía `Intent`. En la siguiente actividad las recibo como String, estas también pueden estar vacías "[]", luego las convierto en `JSONArray` de este modo:

```
//Convertir String a Array - Esto se encuentra en el OnCreate
    try {
        arrayImagenes = new JSONArray(imagenes); // String imagenes
        arrayNotas = new JSONArray(notas); // String notas
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Aquí ademas tengo dos botones, dos Clases Adapter (Correspondiente a cada Array) y un ListView donde muestro los items de cada Array.

Lo siguiente que hago es empezar a listar los objetos del Array en el ListView

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...

// Se muestra por defecto la lista 'Notas' al iniciar la Actividad
    if(arrayNotas == null || arrayNotas.length() == 0) {
        mensajeError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lista.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        lista.setAdapter(new NotasAdapter(context, R.layout.actividad_itemlist, arrayNotas));
        lista.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
```

Luego tengo los botones con los cuales muestro la lista que quiero ver de esta forma:

```
public void buttons() {
    listarNotas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(arrayNotas == null || arrayNotas.length() == 0) {
                mensajeError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lista.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                lista.setAdapter(new NotasAdapter(context, R.layout.actividad_itemlist, arrayNotas));
                lista.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            }
        }
    });

    listarFotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(arrayImagenes == null || arrayImagenes.length() == 0) {
                mensajeError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lista.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                lista.setAdapter(new ImagenesAdapter(context, R.layout.actividad_itemlist, arrayImagenes));
                lista.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Al realizar los procesos de envío de Nota o Carga de Imagen mediante un AsyncTask vuelvo a recibir los arrays pero ya con un objeto cargado en base al proceso realizado así:

```
{
  "id": 8,
  "mes": "Julio",
  ...
  "notas": [
    {
      "id": 37,
      "nota": "Hola Mundo",
      ...
      ...
    }
  "imagenes": [
    // Vacia
   ]
```

En el onPostExecute de cada proceso vuelvo a iniciar la misma Actividad via Intent, enviando de vuelta los arrays de Notas e Imagenes para "Recargar" la Vista y que se visualicen los items agregados.

El envío de notas funciona bien, de hecho después de hacer ese proceso me muestra un item nuevo en la lista de Notas, si pulso el botón de listarFotos me devuelve vacía obviamente y ahora el problema es que si vuelvo a presionar el botón de listarNotas ésta también me devuelve vacía.

Verifiqué si el resultado del AsyncTask me devolvía un item en el array de notas y efectivamente está ahi, entonces porque desaparece? Cabe destacar también que si primero subo una imagen y no una nota, tampoco se visualiza dicho item nuevo en la lista de Imagenes pero si aparece en el resultado del AsyncTask

Comment: en que momento llamas al asynctask? puedes poner ese código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, me llevo algo de tiempo pero creo que ya encontré la solución. Resulta que necesitaba volver a mostrar la visibilidad de la lista en el OnClick de los botones en el caso de que los Arrays ***Tengan Objetos.*** Quedo así:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ...
   ...

// Se muestra por defecto la lista 'Notas' al iniciar la Actividad
if(arrayNotas == null || arrayNotas.length() == 0) {
    mensajeError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lista.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
else {
    mensajeError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    lista.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lista.setAdapter(new NotasAdapter(context, R.layout.actividad_itemlist, arrayNotas));
    lista.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}
```

El método que controla los botones:

```
public void buttons() {
listarNotas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(arrayNotas == null || arrayNotas.length() == 0) {
            mensajeError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lista.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            mensajeError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lista.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lista.setAdapter(new NotasAdapter(context, R.layout.actividad_itemlist, arrayNotas));
            lista.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }
});

listarFotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(arrayImagenes == null || arrayImagenes.length() == 0) {
            mensajeError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lista.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            mensajeError.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lista.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lista.setAdapter(new ImagenesAdapter(context, R.layout.actividad_itemlist, arrayImagenes));
            lista.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }
});
```